# In Android, how to create a Time value?

Tags: android

In my Android app, I'm using the Time class. I understand getting the current time like this:

```
    Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();
```

but what I'm stumbling on is how to create a set value of 8pm in the Time class. It's not just: `Time time8 = "2200";`, because that's a String, and `Time time8 = 2200;` is an integer. So I'm stumped.

Comment: Isn't call to `now.setToNow()` redundant? as `new Time()` will set the time to **NOW**.

Comment: check out the `set` function

Comment: I believe you should be looking in `Calendar` class, not `Time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to that, I think the most easiest for you would be to just set it directly:

set(int second, int minute, int hour, int monthDay, int month, int year)

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = rightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = rightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = rightNow.get(Calendar.YEAR);

Time time8 = new Time();
time8.set(0,0,22,day,month,year);
```

But i would only do it like that if you really want to use `Time` otherwise Calendar is much more useful

```
Calendar calendar8= Calendar.getInstance();
calendar8.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar8.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar8.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,22);
```

Comment: Yeah, Trundlebot, you're right. Calendar is easier, I don't HAVE to use Time.

Answer (score 0):

Could use the calendar class

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,5);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,50);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

Date d = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

From android Dev.

> A specific moment in time, with millisecond precision. Values typically come from currentTimeMillis(), and are always UTC, regardless of the system's time zone. This is often called "Unix time" or "epoch time".

You can do `Date` instead of `time`

```
 Date newdate = new Date();
```

You can use `calendar` to break it down to what you actually need.